How best to translate this もう?
From the Genki II textbook, 3rd edition page 297 (a reading passage about Doraemon):
「これは『アンキパン』だよ。覚えたいことをこのパンに写して、食べてみて。覚えられるから。」のび太くんはパンに写して、全部食べました。もうテストは大丈夫です。
I'm confused about the exact meaning & best translation for this last もう.
My best guess is that it translates like "anymore", but for an affirmative sentence.  For example in the English negative sentence　「もう問題ない。」 "It isn't a problem anymore," the "anymore" implies there was some change of state from "being a problem" to "not being a problem".  I don't think English has a similar word for affirmative sentences, but that's what I'd guess is happening with the もう above.  Am I on the right track?

Yes, that’s what it is.
And English does have a “positive anymore”; it could be used to say “I’ll be passing my tests anymore”.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_anymore?wprov=sfti1#
